# preg_replace for matching a pattern either side of the selector

Tags: php, arrays, regex

If I have this string:

```
I am a @test and I am another@test
```

I want to replace all instances of @words with SPACES before them with another string.

So the above becomes

```
I am a @replace and I am another@test
```

The last part is not replaced because there is no space in front of @

I'm also trying to work this by looping through an array. My code is as follows, but the regex is not correct:

```
$mentioned = [[0] => "@test", [1] => "@anotherword"];
$tweet = "This is a tweet with @test in it and also @anotherword";

foreach ($mentioned as &$mention) {
            $mention = "@".$mention;
            $mention_link = "<a href='#'>".$mention.'</a>';
            preg_replace('/ (@) /', $mention_link, $tweet);
        }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. That's why you're not getting the desired answers. I'm going to help you out a bit. See [this code](https://eval.in/private/9f7cad16f54c28).

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for this regex:

```
(?<!\w)@test
```

And replace by:

```
@replace
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wJ4sE0/2)

**Code:**

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<!\w)@test/im', '@replace', $input);
```

Comment: +1, it also works when the `@` is in first position.

Comment: @Francesca: You need to use ignore case flag `i` if you also want to match `@Test`.[See this updated demo](http://regex101.com/r/wJ4sE0/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=\s)@\S+
```

You can use this simple regex to do the job.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/35

```
$re = "/(?<=\\s)@\\S+/im";
$str = "I am a @test and I am another@test";
$subst = "@replaced";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```